# C++ templated class as subclass or reference?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a templated class that's responsible for copying some data into and out of a local function. I've concocted two different mechanisms for doing this. Either via subclass or via reference. Which makes more sense and is the "right" way to do it?

```
namespace subclass {
struct array {
  int a, b, c, d;
};

template <typename T> class inout : public T {
private:
  static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value);

  T *p;

public:
  inout(T *_p) : p(_p) { memcpy(this, p, sizeof(T)); }
  ~inout(void) { memcpy(p, this, sizeof(T)); }
};

void subr(array *args, int) {
  inout<array> local(args);

  local.a = local.b + local.c + local.d;
}
}

namespace reference {
struct array {
  int a, b, c, d;
};

template <typename T> class inout {
private:
  static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value);

  T *p;
  T &l;

public:
  inout(T &_l, T *_p) : p(_p), l(_l) { memcpy(&l, p, sizeof(T)); }
  ~inout(void) { memcpy(p, &l, sizeof(T)); }
};

void subr(array *args, int) {
  array local;
  inout<array> raii(local, args);

  local.a = local.b + local.c + local.d;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not sure the first one is guaranty to work...

Comment: I stopped reading at `memcpy(this, p, sizeof(T));`

Comment: Sorry, but "concocted" seems to be the key here. I don't know how (or why) you would do this in Java, but in C++ this makes no sense at all. You can pass a reference to your data and don't need to copy anything. And just seeing `memcpy(this` makes my head hurt. This page isn't big enough to quote all the rules that piece violates.

Comment: unless T is always guaranteed to be a primitive type such as `int`, then using `memcpy` is a no-no. Your class instances of type T will likely blow up in spectacular ways after being copied this way.

Comment: I'm glad you all liked this. :) Passing a reference doesn't work because I'm on a system where the reference is coming from a different address space so I need to make a local copy - which is what the memcpy is doing. C++ allows me to ensure that `T` can copied via memcpy and not via a constructor. I've modified my example to ensure `T` can be copyed with `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions seem to me that they try to do a simple thing in a hard way.
If you want to copy, why not simply copy?

```
void subr(array *args, int) {
  array local = *args;

  local.a = local.b + local.c + local.d;

  *args = local;
}
```

If you want an automatic copy at the end of scope as you seem to, again you have simpler:

```
template <typename T>
class AutoCopy {
private:
   T   m_copy;
   T * m_original;

public:
   AutoCopy(T * original) : m_copy(*original), m_original(original) {}
   ~AutoCopy() { *m_original = m_copy; }

   T & get() { return m_copy; }
};

void subr(array *args, int) {
  AutoCopy<array> c(args);
  c.get().a = c.get().b + c.get().c + c.get().d;
}
```

Does it suit you? That way it works even is the type is not a POD, and if it is the regular default copy constructor will be the same as the `memcpy()` (as you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) at the "Trivial copy constructor" section).

And even if you prefer to keep the `memcpy()`, i think that having a member variable and copying into it will be clearer than inheriting from your type.

Comment: Won't work for evil `T = int[42]`... But work around exists :-)